# How can I make the hard color transitions in this image less extreme while still keeping the image quality?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, image-quality, image-editing, paint.net

So I have this image.

[image]

In the image, there are hard changes in color like this.

[image: also an image]

In paint.net, how can I make those transitions less extreme without losing any of the image quality and tileability?

I know the image looks horrible right now, it is still a work in progress. The image was resized and cropped due to the size limits of uploading. Answers for GIMP, Photoshop, and other programs are also appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this myself in GIMP. I just used the heal tool to make the image look nicer, then I used the Tile Seamless Filter to regain tileability.

Answer (score 1):

Frequency separation would allow you to treat the colour separately from the texture

I [very quickly] separated & smudged your circled area on the Low frequency layer...

[image]

add that back to the high frequency layer

[image]

& you get...

[image]

Obviously, with a bit more care & attention, you can do better than that ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Using Photoshop**

1) Use color range to select the less vibrant/darker pixels. Go to Select -> Color Range. Use the eye dropper tool to select a dark part of the photo. Hit OK

[image: Selection Area]

2) While you have an active selection, create a vibrance or saturation layer. Turn up the vibrance. This will make a mask of the adjustment layer to only effect the darker pixels from the color range.

[image: Vibrance]

3) Use levels or curves to darken the image.

4) Use the spot healing brush on the hard edges.

[image: Spot Heal]

Final image of the bottom left of the image.

[image: final]

Comment: The only problem with this is if I use it on the sides of the image, it would lose tileability.